# Bracha near a bathroom

Tags: halacha, bathroom, lifnei-iver

Note -- I am not asking about the whether one is allowed to pray near a bathroom in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66740/saying-brachos-near-a-bathroom) sense.

As per the rules on [this](https://www.torahmusings.com/2011/08/bathroom-etiquette/) website, thinking Torah thoughts is not allowed in a bathroom. As such, would I be wrong to say any sort of prayer near a bathroom that is occupied by someone who would hear what I am saying? If I know that the person would listen to my bracha (for example) and say [Amen](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19119/answering-amen-to-quiet-berachoth) to it then I would be causing the person to think about Torah while in an inappropriate location, and my actions create a michshol.

This is a question about theory though it has practical roots as many kitchens have a powder room and if someone goes to the bathroom while someone else gets food (or washes for bread etc) and can hear the bracha being said, he would respond, or at least think of the halachot of brachot.

Comment: Were this true, many shuls would have to pause dozens of times every morning.

Comment: Instead of asking about a ברכה, which may possibly lead to Torah thoughts, I recommend you ask about studying Torah aloud near a bathroom.

Answer (score 1):

A modern lavatory is much cleaner than a talmudic era latrine. Unless the bathroom exudes a pungent stench or there is visible excrement, it doesn't trigger any prohibitions, however, we avoid it as a fence.