# Can one say a berakha in a locker room?

Tags: halacha, blessing

Can one say a berakha in a locker room? For instance, after using the restroom to say 'Asher yatsar', or when putting on talet katan to say '`al mitsvat tsitsit', or before and after eating a protein bar/drinking a protein shake.

Comment: A lot of locker rooms have a separate area for toilets and lockers and changing rooms, no?

Comment: Most locker rooms have toilets that are separated by walls but don't necessarily have doors to be considered different rooms. Which is why I ask the question. Is it enough for the toilets to be separated by a wall, or does the restroom has to have a door in order to be considered a different room from the changing room.

Comment: Judging that since many shuls I've been two have two doors between the sanctuary and the restroom, I'd assume there needs to be a door. But I could be wrong.

Comment: I have to hunt a bit, but I sense that there's a M.Y. question that addresses the idea that a wall is sufficient. I think the main concern with making a bracha is that there should be no foul odor of urine or feces nearby. I don't think sweat odor is a problem. The other part is if there's a problem making a bracha around other nude people.

Comment: @DanF I didn't consider the issue about saying a bracha around nudity. You are right, one is not allowed to mention haShem's name with ones genitals exposed or in front of other people who are naked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can provided that

- you wear underwear or a bathrobe and ideally a Tshirt and a kippa (see [here](http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/25-The-Right-Environment.html))
- you turn away from nudity (closing your eyes is not sufficient)
- your hands are clean
- you are four amot from any source of foul odors (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/blessing-underneath-bathroom/2647#2647) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53389/can-one-recite-prayers-or-learn-torah-while-facing-a-bathroom-whose-door-is-open/53502#53502))
- you do not see *tzo'ah* (feces)

See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53389/can-one-recite-prayers-or-learn-torah-while-facing-a-bathroom-whose-door-is-open/66761#66761) for a question on praying and learning Torah when a bathroom door is open. [My answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66761/11501) contains more sources backing up the above.

For original sources, see Mishne Torah, Hilchot Kriat Shema [3:3 and following](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Reading_the_Shema.3.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Of course, [ask your rav](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) before implementing anything you read here.

Comment: Offhand, for most locker rooms, it seems like nudity is the main impediment. Of course, there are many different types of locker rooms, anyway. I'm assuming you're referring to a pool or gym locker room or where there are showers. Some physical therapy places have locker rooms, but as there are no showers, it's less likely that there would be nudity in such places.

Comment: I am referring to gym locker rooms with showers.